# Why is perchloric acid stronger than perbromic acid?

Tags: acid-base

Since chlorine has a larger electronegativity than bromine, why is perchloric acid a strong acid, while perbromic acid is not?  We clearly see that electronegativity affects an acid's strength with hydrofluoric acid being much weaker than hydrochloric acid, due to fluorine's high electronegativity.  Wouldn't chlorine's higher electronegativity make it harder for perchloric acid to dissociate than perbromic acid like it does for hydrofluoric acid?